# Convert passed string value(without date format) into DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a way to convert string such as `31072015` (This can be any date passed as in string without format) which is today's date 31/07/2015 into a DateTime.

I have tried `Convert.ToDateTime` method and `DateTime.Parse` throw `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`exception.

I understand, this means I need to pass the string in some format such as 31/07/2015. But the string value passed in cannot be in that specified format.

I have thought about splitting the string and adding the "/" into it but I am not sure how to go about that as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`

for example

`DateTime.ParseExact(someDateString, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var date = "31072015";
DateTime dateValue;
if ((DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue)))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this common function

Common method:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(this object Value,string Format)
        {
            DateTime dateTime;            
            DateTime.TryParseExact(Value.ToString(), Format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
            return dateTime;
        }

Sample:

int Intdates = 31072015;
DateTime Date = Intdates.ToDateTime("DDMMyyyy")
```